# iOS 9 GM - AVPlayerLayer video rendering

Tags: avplayer, avplayerlayer, ios-9-beta5

Since iOS 9 GM is out there i started getting strange effect on iPhone 6 and 6 plus (running the iOS 9 GM maybe on all iPhones). I am using base SDK iOS 8 latest oficial. I am not sure what might be causing this problem but i will try to explain my current view configuration.
1) The AVPlayerLayer is added as sublayer in a view that is added as subview in a tableviewHeaderView
2) The view that holds the AVPlayerLayer is using autoresizing masks and translating to autolayout
Here is the result:
1) The sound is aways playing but the video is sometimes presented when the layoutSubviews is called and the view that holds the AVPlayerLayer changes it's frame to make it fullscreen.
2) If the app is started in landscape mode videos are playing with image and sound

I have tried various potential fixes, however i haven't achieved any consistent success.

Comment: Have you been able to find a solution to this since September? I have a similar issue, and can't find a solution.

Comment: One of the things that might solve that issue is to manually change the frame of the AVPlayerLayer and make it really big (that's how i solved it). If you still have the problem, you maybe need to modify your code to first load the underlying asset's 'playable' key prior to starting playback?